# I have two tables i want to join them in my SQL to retrieve results

Tags: sql

I am a newbie for SQL. I have two tables:

**Table_1**

```
Property_ID  Agent_ID
1200           1111
1201           1112
1202           1112
```

**Table_2**

```
Agent_ID      Agent_Email     Agent_Address
1112          abc@gm.com      124 something estate
```

I have the property id. What I want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1
WHERE Property_ID = '[I have this id in a variable]'
```

and then:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_2
WHERE Agent_ID = '[Agent Id we get from first query]'
```

But I want to do it in a single query. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a join, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1 T1
JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T2.Agent_ID = T1.Agent_ID
WHERE T1.Property_Id = ...
```

If you want to filter the results further, add an "AND [condition]" after the WHERE clause.  You can find a lot of info on JOINs out there, here is one place that shows some good intro examples:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Table1.PropertyID, 
        Table2.AgentID
FROM    Table1 Table1
        INNER JOIN Table2 Table2
           ON Table1.AgentID = Table2.AgentID
WHERE   Table1.PropertyID = '...'
```

Comment: you mentioned Table1 Table1 two times is that mandatory ?

Comment: No, it's not. That's just how you'll be referncing the table in the query. You could exclude it altogether, or use something shortened like T1. Just make sure to prefix column names with the table name if a column is shared by two or more tables in your query.

Answer (score 0):

select * 
from Table_1 t1
join Table_2 t2 on t1.Agent_ID = t2.Agent_ID
where t1.Property_ID = '[I have this id in a variable]' and t2.Agent_ID = '[Agent Id we get from first query]'